# Can we use adverbs with Comparative adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, comparatives

1. He is **much** taller than me.

Vs

2. He is **incredibly** taller than me.

Can we use incredibly here, with a  comparative adjective(taller) ?

Comment: In some contexts,you can qualify the comparative, in some you can't. There is no "rule" - it is contextual. "The witch gives a magic potion to my young brother and suddenly he is incredibly taller." "I put oil on the lock and it is quickly easier to open."

Comment: “My younger sister is, incredibly, taller than I am.” Incredibly is modifying “is”, not taller. It is expressing amazement, not saying she’s very much taller or a great deal taller.

Comment: Same with G’s examples. Quickly easier doesn’t say how much easier, it just says it happened fast.

Comment: @Xanne, OP ends the sentence in ...than me, but you have refined it as ...than I am. Just an observation!

Comment: No, you can't modify comparative adjectives with _ly_-adverbs.